# How to convert NSImage contentsOfURL to String in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, nsimage

I need the contentsOfURL out of `NSImage` and convert that to `String`.

I have a conf.txt file and in that file i would safe the contentsOfURL from `NSImage`.

Not working:

Write:

```
for i in 0 ..< RunnerFaces.count {
        name = RunnerFaces[i].RunnerName + space
        speed = String(RunnerFaces[i].RunnerSpeed) + space
        img1 = String(RunnerFaces[i].RunnerImage1) + space
        img2 = String(RunnerFaces[i].RunnerImage2) + space

        strz = name+speed+img1+img2

    str.append(strz)
    }
```

Read:

```
for _ in 0 ..< safedRunner {
                name = loadSplit[0]
                speed = loadSplit[1]
                img1 = loadSplit[2]
                img2 = loadSplit[3]

            RunnerFaces.append(RunnerFace(RunnerName: name, RunnerSpeed: Double(speed)!, RunnerImage1: NSImage(imageLiteral: img1), RunnerImage2: NSImage(imageLiteral: img2)))

            for _ in 0 ..< 4{
                loadSplit.removeAtIndex(0)
            }

        }
```

Write & Read works only the `NSImage` crash..

Comment: As far as I know `NSImage(imageLiteral:)` can only be used in a Playground.

Comment: @vadian Yes, `NSImage/imageLiteral:)` don't work. Do you have a alternative? Or some other tips?

Comment: Use a property list rather than a text file and save the image as `NSData`.